How to delete and recover emails from gmail using thunderbird and the IMAP protocol?
The question is very explicit and straight forward. I think there is some feature missing here. I'm not sure if its a Thunderbird bug or if its Gmail's fault. I want to be able to delete a message and recover it, that's it.
I've followed the instructions on both of this links and for this particular thing of deleting and recovering mail they don't seem to work.
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/thunderbird-and-gmail
https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78892#zippy=%2Cthunderbird
What I'm experiencing right now:

I have Thunderbird configured to access my Gmail account through IMAP, and other diverse accounts that don't matter.
I select a message and press the delete key or right click menu -> small trash can icon with the hint label "Delete Message".
Thunderbird marks the message, striked trough the subject, but still there. The normal thing would be sending the message to the trash folder, but ok, just marking it is fine by me.
The next time Thunderbird synchronize, it deletes the message. I mean is no longer visible on the inbox.
If I unmark the message before the synchronization, right click menu -> small trash can icon with "Undelete Message" hint, when the next synchronization occurs, it gets deleted any way.
I have the "Don't delete any messages" option selected in my settings, as the instructions in the previous links told me, so I think this behavior is wrong.

The implications of this behavior are that if I accidentally delete an important email there is no way to get it back.
So, now with that bit more of context, how do I delete and then recover a message, and keep that message, when I use Thunderbird as my client for my Gmail account through the IMAP protocol?
Any hint would be appreciated.
Update 2024-11-25:
I read the answer by @grawity and tested the settings presented by him and there is a partial answer there, I might work with this. Also it turns out that in synchronization settings of Thunderbird I had the synchronization disabled for the Trash and the Spam folders. I enabled them and now I can move messages to the trash and back to the inbox. That's valid work around. In the web client, I noticed that Gmail has 2 special folders (I should say labels) "[imap]/Sent" and "[imap]/Trash" and this is the trash that synchronizes with my Thunderbird's trash folder. Any way the only problem that remains is that deleting a message on Thunderbird, with the delete key or right click menu delete, doesn't move that message to the trash it just disappears. It doesn't disappears completely, it still can be found in the "All Mail" folder but its not in the trash where it should go and where the setting "when I delete a message ... move it to this folder : Trash" says it should go.
By the way a little description of my setup, should've done it earlier:

3 linux PCs, 1 desktop, 2 laptops. All sharing the same gmail account and Thunderbird 128.4.3.
1 laptop with Pop!_Os 22.04 AMD64 kernel 6.9.
The other laptop and desktop using debian 12 (stable bookworm) AMD64 kernel 6.1.


This seems like it's an issue with Thunderbird itself - have you tried disabling the options mentioned here? Provided the options are configured as set in the second link in the question, the email client should be moving deleted messages to the Trash folder when using IMAP, which seems to indicate either an option is misconfigured or it's a programming issue in Thunderbird (you may also want to consider emailing Thunderbird's tech support)

@JW0914 Thanks for trying but this setting didn't do the trick, I selected the option to disable inbox filters on my gmail settings, made some test, everything is exactly the same. I think your right this must be a problem on Thunderbird's side, I'll try the tech support.


Thunderbird marks the message, striked trough the subject, but still there. The normal thing would be sending the message to the trash folder, but ok, just marking it is fine by me.

Marking as deleted was the normal thing in traditional IMAP (i.e. not Gmail's weird IMAP). The messages stay there until a) the "Compact" or "Expunge" button is used (Thunderbird calls it "Compact"), b) the client automatically performs "Expunge" on exit, or c) you're using Gmail and you have auto-expunge enabled in the Gmail web interface's settings under "POP/IMAP".
If the struck-through messages disappear on next sync, that's most likely the Gmail IMAP server deleting them due to its "Auto-Expunge on" option.
If you want to use the Trash folder, select that in Thunderbird's account settings (auto-expunge should stay enabled in this case):



Account Settings








If you want "Mark as deleted" to work as it does with regular IMAP, disable auto-expunge in Gmail's webmail settings:



Forwarding and POP/IMAP








